# c# MailMessage From email address display name is not working

Tags: c#, mailmessage, email-address

I tried to send an email and set display name of the from Email address. But when i received email in my client for instance gmail. Instead of display name i see email address without domain means From Email "FromEmail@abc.com"  then when i received it shows me i received email from "FromEmail".

Here is my code

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

mail.From = new MailAddress("FromEmail@abc.com","Automate");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("ToEmail@abc.com"));
mail.Subject = "This is test email";
mail.Body = "This is test mail.";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("senderEmail@abc.com", "*****");
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: No one looking this :(